# Getting Start-Process to wait in a PSSession

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to run an exe in a remote session, and access the results once it has executed

if I try locally:

```
Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath ping -ArgumentList "1.1.1.1 -n 5 -w 3000" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru  }
```

where the process is a long running ping:

```
  Start-Process -FilePath ping -ArgumentList "1.1.1.1 -n 5 -w 3000" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```

i get output, and it waits. but if I apply the same command to a session (after creating a New-PSSession)

```
Invoke-Command  -Session $serviceSession  -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath ping -ArgumentList "1.1.1.1 -n 5 -w 3000" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru  }
```

it returns straight away.
How do I get the results of this. I really want to use Start-Process, because I can access the ExitCode from the process. and I find $LASTEXITCODE is not reliable for the exe i want to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use `Start-Process -PassThru` you need to assign that to a variable so you can then check the process's exit code e.g.:

```
{ $p = Start-Process ... -Wait -PassThru; $p.ExitCode }
```

That said, I've had no issues with $LastExitCode and find that a solution like this works rather nicely:

```
$res = icm acme1 { $r = ping.exe 1.1.1.1 -n 5 -w 3000; [pscustomobject]@{Output=$r;ExitCode=$LastExitCode} }

$res
$res.ExitCode
$res.Output
```